# Trouble using Telnet in perl?

Tags: perl, telnet

I'm having some trouble send commands and receiving text/data from the telnet connection that I set up.

```
 #!perl
 #Telnet.pl

use Net::Telnet;

# Create a new instance of Net::Telnet, 
my $telnetCon = new Net::Telnet (Timeout => 20,
                                Dump_Log   => "dump.log",
                                Input_Log => "infile.log",
                                Output_log => "output.log",
                                Prompt => '/\$ $/') or die "Could not make connection.";

# Connect to the host of the users choice                                
$telnetCon->open('');

#get username and password from user
my $CXusername = '';
my $CXpassword = '';

my $task = '50104'; # Get this input from the search

# Recreate the login
# Wait for the login: message and then enter the username
$telnetCon->waitfor(match => '/login:/i');

# this method adds a \n to the end of the username, it mimics hitting the enter key after entering your username
$telnetCon->print($CXusername);

$telnetCon->waitfor(match => '/Password:/i');

# does the same as the previous command but for the password
$telnetCon->print($CXpassword);

#Wait for the login successful message
$telnetCon->waitfor(match => '/$/');

$telnetCon->cmd("viewtask 50104");
$telnetCon->cmd(" ");
$telnetCon->cmd(" ");

@output = $telnetCon->cmd("who");
print @output;

($output) = $telnetCon->waitfor(match => '/$/');

print "Output: ",$output;

if($searched =~ /MODIFIED files in Task $_[1] :(.*?)The/s){
    # to Logout of the telnet connection
    $telnetCon->print("exit");

    #return the modified data 
    return $1;
}
```

Tell me if the question doesn't make sense, I'll try and reword it.
[image: First View]
[image: Second View]

So this is the telnet view. I get stuck on the first image when i enter the $telnetCon->cmd("viewtask 50140"). I want to get to the second image and continue entering commands into my telnet session.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your question, `$telnetCon->cmd(" ");` times out? is `viewtask` waiting for input, by any chance?

Comment: Umm kinda when i initial enter viewtask... it prints some of the file and then waits for another input to continue showing the rest of the file

Answer (score 1):

The `Net::Telnet` `cmd` method writes your command (with a `\n` appended) and waits for the prompt. this is incompatible with your program's waiting for input to complete output.

I think in your case you would want to use a combination of `print` and `getlines` and/or `waitfor` to get this to work

Comment: I tried both but no luck, with getlines it prints everything up until, and including, the command

Comment: @Shahab: If I understand correctly, you should be able to do something like `...->print("yourcmd");` `...->waitfor(/^:/);` `...->print("");` and so on

Comment: Weird thing, it doesn't match : at the beginning of the line